# Use same component for multiple IP in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have multiple instances of the same IP in my Vivado project. All of them expose the same ports but are configured differently internally. Let's say I have three of them for now

- axi_data_samples_0_FIFO
- axi_data_samples_1_FIFO
- axi_data_samples_2_FIFO

with the following architecture :

```vhdl
    component axi_data_samples_N_FIFO
    port (
        wr_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        wr_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        wr_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        valid : out STD_LOGIC;
    );
    end component;
```

In my code, I use a generic to know if I have to instantiate 0, 1, or 2. This lead to something like this :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL;

use work.JESD_INTERFACE_PKG.ALL;

entity samples_interface is
    generic (
        INSTANCE_MODEL: integer := 1
    );
end samples_interface;

architecture behavioral of samples_interface is
    component axi_data_samples_0_FIFO
    port (
        wr_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        wr_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        wr_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        valid : out STD_LOGIC;
    );
    end component;

    component axi_data_samples_1_FIFO
    port (
        wr_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        wr_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        wr_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        valid : out STD_LOGIC;
    );
    end component;

    component axi_data_samples_2_FIFO
    port (
        wr_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        wr_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        wr_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        rd_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(255 - 1 downto 0);
        valid : out STD_LOGIC;
    );
    end component;

    -- Some code
begin
    -- Some code

    instance_0_i: if INSTANCE_MODEL = 0 then
        fifo_i : axi_data_samples_0_FIFO
        port map (
            wr_clk => in_clk,
            wr_rst => RST,
            wr_en => fifo_samples_in_valid_r,
            din => fifo_vector_in,
    
            rd_clk => out_clk,
            rd_rst => RST_out,
            rd_en => out_samples_enable,
            dout => fifo_vector_out,
            valid => fifo_samples_out_valid
        );
    end generate;

    instance_1_i: if INSTANCE_MODEL = 1 then
        fifo_i : axi_data_samples_1_FIFO
        port map (
            wr_clk => in_clk,
            wr_rst => RST,
            wr_en => fifo_samples_in_valid_r,
            din => fifo_vector_in,
    
            rd_clk => out_clk,
            rd_rst => RST_out,
            rd_en => out_samples_enable,
            dout => fifo_vector_out,
            valid => fifo_samples_out_valid
        );
    end generate;

    instance_2_i: if INSTANCE_MODEL = 2 then
        fifo_i : axi_data_samples_2_FIFO
        port map (
            wr_clk => in_clk,
            wr_rst => RST,
            wr_en => fifo_samples_in_valid_r,
            din => fifo_vector_in,
    
            rd_clk => out_clk,
            rd_rst => RST_out,
            rd_en => out_samples_enable,
            dout => fifo_vector_out,
            valid => fifo_samples_out_valid
        );
    end generate;
end behavioral;
```

In my real project, I don't have 3 instances, but 8 of them with 26 ports each.
For now, my code is basically unreadable. So I'm looking for a way to simplify it since all components have the same ports and are an instance of the same IP. I was thinking about a configuration declaration but I'm not really sure how to use it in that case.

Any idea?

Comment: The [generate statement](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/generate.html) should do the trick.

Comment: How ? I don't see how I am supposed to use it since I want to change the name of the component

Comment: @Qiu a generate statement is no use here because the component name is different, and you cannot construct an identifier in VHDL using strings. Apart from fixing the generate syntax in your code above, because they are all xilinx IPs, you're basically stuck with the long list of instantiations you have. If there is other code in this file, then the other option for tidyup is to create a wrapper entity that instantiates the correct one but only presents the single port list in this file (you'll still have a long list inside the wrapper - but at least its partly hidden)

Comment: I think a configuration is the answer; it effectively allows a renaming of a selected entity  into the component you instantiate. The configuration may be better in a different file...

Comment: Configuration specification (IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.3) and a Configuration declaration (a primary design unit found in 3.4, likely the preferred solution). FPGA vendors don't support configuration declarations while most support configuration specifications as block declarative items. Unlike a configuration declaration, a block declarative item implies editing and re-analyzing one or more architectures/blocks and can't be in a different file. You could as easily specify different architectures for the same entity. You're at the tender mercy of the vendor without 'a way to simplify it'.

Comment: Vivado v2020.2 UG901 Synthesis, Ch 5. VHDL Support, Table 5-10 VHDL Constructs and Support Status, "Configuration  Supported only with the *all* clause for instances list." which lets out any schemes to save complexity in a design specification.